# How would I structure a program that determines the next bus depart?

Tags: ios, algorithm, pseudocode

I am looking to make an iOS app that displays how long until the bus departs from the terminal. The user has the option to check off between 1 and 5 of the busses. For example, say there are 5 busses, all that could potentially depart the terminal at different times (they don't all leave the terminal at :30 for example). To add on to that, each day of the week changes the depart time of that bus. Also, some busses do not run on certain days. So basically to sum it up..

-The busses have different depart times depending on what day of the week it is
-Not all of the busses run 7 days of the week

I am a bit overwhelmed on what way to go about approaching how to structure this program. My initial thought is to make a class for each of the 5 busses. I would determine whether the user has selected to check the next depart time of a bus. For example, the user can check depart times for all of the 5 busses if they wanted to. If the user checks off all 5 busses, the app would display the next depart time for all 5 of them. If the user only wants to show 1 of the busses next depart times, they only check off that 1 bus.

So as far as the starting logic goes, I would think to check if the bus was checked off in the first place:

if(bus1CheckedOff)
   //

if(bus2CheckedOff)
   //

if(bus3CheckedOff)
   //

if(bus4CheckedOff)
   //

if(bus5CheckedOff)
   //

From there, I need to get the next depart time. I would think to write a class for each day and store all info for each of the 5 busses in there. So a class for Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday.

Then I would find out the date and time on the user's iOS device and depending on day, go to that class, and filter through an array of times, and return whichever time is closest (making sure it hasn't passed yet)?

if(bus1CheckedOff)
{
   if(isMonday)
      //

else if(isTuesday)
      //

else if(isWednesday)
      //

else if(isThursday)
      //

else if(isFriday)
      //

else if(isSaturday)
      //

else if(isSunday)
      //
}

if(bus2CheckedOff)
   //

if(bus3CheckedOff)
   //

if(bus4CheckedOff)
   //

if(bus5CheckedOff)
   //

I am rambling, all in all just looking for an efficient structure to write this application. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a class for each bus and for each weekday. The idea of classes is to encapsulate common behaviour so that individual instances can use it. In particular, if your code has many similar lines like your suggestions above, it might be worth rethinking the data structures.

I would creat a `Bus` class (where bus really means bus service) with a line number, destination and list of time tables plus a method to return the time table for a specific day. It also needs to know whether it is checked in the app. Then you can have a list of (any number of, not just five) bus services that start from the terminal and you can check whether they should be considered in a loop.

I'd also write a system to classify days. There are the seven week days, of course, but also broader categories like workdays, weekends and public holidays. This system has a hierarchy: Broad categories have low priority, special days have high priority.

Then you need to determine how to store the timetables. The easiest would be to have a map of day categories and lists of times.

```
class Bus
    public
        String destination
        String service
        bool checked

        Time[] timetable(Day):
            if day in times:
                return times[day]
            if holiday(day) and "Holiday" in times:
                return times["Holiday"]
            if weekday(day) in times:
                return times[weekday(day)]
            if "Everyday" in times:
                return times["Everyday"]
            return []

        void add(Day, Time[])

    private
        Time[][Day] times

Bus bus[] = []

Bus b1("1", "Forest View")
b1.add(Weekend, [0845, 1045, 1245, 1540])
b1.add(Workday, [0845, 0945, 1045, 1145, 1245,
    1420, 1520, 1620, 1820, 2020, 2220])
b1.add("Dec 25", [1300])
bus.add(b1)

Bus b5("5", "Mountain View")
b5.add(Everyday, [0800, 0900, 0930, 1000, 1030, 1100, 1130,
    1200, 1300, 1400, 1430, 1530, 1600, 1630, 1700, 1800,
    1900, 2000, 2200, 2230])
b5.add(Sunday, [1000, 1200, 1600, 1800])
bus.add(b5)

Bus gc("Grand Circuit", "via Ocean View")
gc.add(Everyday, [0835, 1035, 1235, 1635])
bus.add(gc)
```

You can find the departing times of all buses in a loop. Add them to a list of tuples of times and services and sort that list by departure times:

```
# helper class to relate times and bus services
public class Departure
    Time time
    Bus bus

Departure dep[] = []
day = "Mar 23"
foreach b in bus:
    if b.checked():
        tt = timetable(day)
        foreach t in tt:
            dep.add(Departure(t, b))

dep.sort()      # sort by time

for d in dep:
    print d.time, d.bus.service, d.bus.destination
```

Voilà! This should give you

```
08:35    Grand Circuit - via Ocean View
08:45    1 - Forest View
10:00    5 - Mountain View
10:35    Grand Circuit - via Ocean View
10:45    1 - Forest View
12:00    5 - Mountain View
12:35    Grand Circuit - via Ocean View
12:45    1 - Forest View
15:40    1 - Forest View
16:00    5 - Mountain View
16:35    Grand Circuit - via Ocean View
18:00    5 - Mountain View
```